# Find minimum of vector in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Since last night I have been trying out `Rcpp` and `inline`, and so far I am really enjoying it. But I am kinda new to `C` in general and can only do basic stuff yet, and I am having a hard time finding help online on things like functions.

Something I was working on was a function that finds the minimum of a vector in the global environment. I came up with:

```
library("inline")
library("Rcpp")

foo <- rnorm(100)

bar <- cxxfunction( signature(),
'
Environment e = Environment::global_env();  
NumericVector foo = e["foo"];
int min;

for (int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++)
{
    if ( foo[i] < foo[min] ) min = i;
}
return wrap(min+1);
', plugin = "Rcpp")

bar()
```

But it seems like there should be an easier way to do this, and it is quite slower than `which.max()`

```
system.time(replicate(100000,bar()))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.27    0.00    0.26 
system.time(replicate(100000,which.min(foo)))
   user  system elapsed 
    0.2     0.0     0.2
```

Am I overlooking a basic `c++` or `Rcpp` function that does this? And if so, where could I find a list of such functions?

I guess this question is related to:
[Where can I learn how to write C code to speed up slow R functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106174/where-can-i-learn-to-how-to-write-c-code-to-speed-up-slow-r-functions)

but different in that I am not really interested in how to incorporate `c++` in `R`, but more on how and where to learn basic `c++` code that is usable in `R`.

Comment: I highly doubt you'll speed up operations like min and max using C++ -- these are probably already implemented using (fast) SSE instructions in R. Plus, the transition from C++ to R and vice versa is not free.

Comment: I realize that, this is more meant conceptual, and this is part of a much larger c++ function I am trying to implement in R.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Glad you are finding Rcpp useful.

The first comment by Billy is quite correct. There is overhead in the function lookup and there is overhead in the `[]` lookup for each element etc.

Also, a much more common approach is to take a vector you have in R, pass it to a compiled function you create via inline and Rcpp, and have it return the result. Try that. There are plenty of examples in the package and scattered over the rcpp-devel mailing list archives.

*Edit:* I could not resist trying to set up a very C++ / STL style answer.

```
R> src <- '
+   Rcpp::NumericVector x(xs);
+   Rcpp::NumericVector::iterator it =       // iterator type
+     std::min_element(x.begin(), x.end());  // STL algo
+   return Rcpp::wrap(it - x.begin()); '
R> minfun <- cxxfunction(signature(xs="numeric"), body=src, plugin="Rcpp")
R> minfun(c(7:20, 3:5))
[1] 14
R>
```

That is not exactly the easiest answer but it shows how by using what C++ offers you can find a minimum element without an (explicit) loop even at the C++ level.  But the builtin `min()` function is still faster.

*Edit 2: Corrected as per Romain's comment below.

Comment: But your STL version implements `min`, which is not what Sacha wanted : `which.min`.

Comment: Well spotted -- but as `min_element()` returns an iterator, we can fix that easily as I have just done -- on the example it now (correctly) returns 14.

Comment: Rcpp 0.9.16 will have `which_min`