# How much faster is C than R in practice?

Tags: c, r

I wrote a Gibbs sampler in R and decided to port it to C to see whether it would be faster. A lot of pages I have looked at claim that C will be up to 50 times faster, but every time I have used it, it's only about five or six times faster than R. My question is: is this to be expected, or are there tricks which I am not using which would make my C code significantly faster than this (like how using vectorization speeds up code in R)? I basically took the code and rewrote it in C, replacing matrix operations with for loops and making all the variables pointers.

Also, does anyone know of good resources for C from the point of view of an R programmer? There's an excellent book called *The Art of R Programming* by Matloff, but it seems to be written from the perspective of someone who already knows C.

Also, the screen tends to freeze when my C code is running in the standard R GUI for Windows. It doesn't crash; it unfreezes once the code has finished running, but it stops me from doing anything else in the GUI. Does anybody know how I could avoid this? I am calling the function using .C()

Comment: Unless you **really** know and *understand* C, there will be very little performance enhancements to be had. As to why the freezing occurs, it's all about threading. My guess is that R will auto-execute in the background, wheras C most definitely will not.

Comment: It depends. As long as you stick to the primitives, they should be about the same. When you code three nested {i,j,k} loops to implement a matrix multiplication, C will be faster. (not if you would use the matrix/vector primitives)

Comment: To add to what @RichardJ.RossIII said, always remember that you're never just comparing languages, you're also comparing _your ability to program in each language_ at the same time. It can be hard to disentangle to two.

Comment: What @RichardJ.RossIII said.  C allows you to squeeze a lot of performance out of the hardware when you need it, but that doesn't all come for free.  You have to know what you're doing and understand *why* your code is running slower than it could be with some low level optimization.

Comment: BTW: My guess is that the .C() function links and calls a shared library function. And for sanity reasons, it will freeze the other threads, giving the .C() thingy exclusive access to all "global" data structures. There is another (fork/exec + wait) calling convention in R, but it had a different name. exec, IIRC.

Comment: For your second paragraph, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106174/where-can-i-learn-to-how-to-write-c-code-to-speed-up-slow-r-functions

Comment: Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11275230/636656) of Rcpp producing huge speed-ups relative to even optimized R code, but in the end they turned out to be due to the primitives as @wildplasser noted.  In this case, the speed advantage was because Rcpp was modifying the original object rather than modifying a copied object.  *When C(++) code performed the same fundamental operations as the R code, it was similarly fast, but C allowed more control over which operations were performed.*

Comment: Do a loop benchmark, with SIMD in C, and SIMD in R--but you have to access particular libraries to access SIMD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213060/does-r-leverage-simd-when-doing-vectorized-calculations  SIMD does indeed offer about 4-6x speed-up, assuming you have done a perfect implementation otherwise.  If you can't submerge your R loops into a SIMD compiled library call, it's likely it will never equal C.  But if you can, R is a lazy functional coding system -- there isn't much overhead even though it is interpreted -- so you should be identical to C under the interpretation layer

Answer (score 15):

Many of the existing posts have *explicit examples* you can run, for example Darren Wilkinson has several posts on his blog analyzing this in different languages, and later even on different hardware (eg comparing his high-end laptop to his netbook and to a Raspberry Pi). Some of his posts are

- [the initial (then revised) post](http://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/gibbs-sampler-in-various-languages-revisited/)
- [another later post](http://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/faster-gibbs-sampling-mcmc-from-within-r/)

and there are many more on his site -- these often compare C, Java, Python and more.

Now, I also turned this into a version using [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) -- see  [this blog post](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/07/14/#rcpp_gibbs_example).  We also used the same example in a comparison between Julia, Python and R/C++ at useR this summer so you should find plenty other examples and references. MCMC is widely used, and "easy pickings" for speedups.

Given these examples, allow me to add that I disagree with the two earlier comments your question received. The speed will *not* be the same, it is easy to do better in an example such as this, and your C/C++ skills will mostly determines how much better.

Finally, an often overlooked aspect is that the *speed of the RNG* matters a lot. Running down loops and adding things up is cheap -- doing "good" draws is not, and a lot of inter-system variation comes from that too.

Comment: Thanks for linking to those posts with a real-world example! The examples I have seen in the past have mostly been artificial ones, eg. adding up the first million positive integers.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph, I couldn't really see a good way to generate uniform random numbers in C, so I just generated as many random numbers as I needed in R before starting, and then passed a pointer to that array as one of the arguments of the C function. I am not sure whether this is better or worse than generating them in C?

Comment: Please see [Writing R Extension, Section 6.3](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Random-numbers) or the documentation of any good numerical library. Rcpp gives you this for free, even *vectorised* ie one call and a vector of N rngs drawn. At compiled speed.

Comment: Do you mean that C takes a lot of time to peek and poke? Should this be avoided?

Comment: Function calls have overheads. Fewer total calls, faster execution.

Comment: The function call overhead in C++ is pretty small (on the order of nanoseconds), it does add up if you're doing millions of calls.

Answer (score 2):

About the GUI freezing, you might want to call `R_CheckUserInterrupt` and perhaps `R_ProcessEvents` every now and then.

Answer (score 2):

I would say C, done properly, is much faster than R.

Some easy gains you could try:
Set the compiler to optimize for more speed.
Compiling with the -march flag.
Also if you're using VS, make sure you're compiling with release options, not debug.

Answer (score 1):

Your observed performance difference will depend on a number of things: the type of operations that you are doing, how you write the C code, what type of compiler-level optimizations you use, your target CPU architecture, etc etc.

You can write basic, sloppy C and get something that works and runs with decent efficiency.  You can also fine-tune your code for the unique characteristics of your target CPU - perhaps invoking specialized assembly instructions - and squeeze every last drop of performance that you can out of the code.  You could even write code that runs significantly *slower* than the R version.  C gives you a lot of flexibility.  The limiting factor here is how much time that you want to put into writing and optimizing the C code.

The reverse is also true (duplicate the previous paragraph here, but swap "C" and "R").

I'm not trying to sound facetious, but there's really not a straightforward answer to your question.  The only way to tell how much faster your C version would be is to write the code both ways and benchmark them.

Comment: "_You could even write code that runs significantly slower than the R version._"  -- No, not really.