# Vectorize min() for matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

I'm hoping to vectorize the following loop:

```
for (i in 1:n) {
    for (j in 1:m) {
        temp_mat[i,j]=min(temp_mat[i,j],1);
    }
}
```

I thought I could do `temp_mat=min(temp_mat,1)`, but this is not giving me the desired result. Is there a way to vectorize this loop to make it much faster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `temp_mat <- pmin(temp_mat, 1)`. See `?pmin` for more use of parallel minima.

Example:

```
set.seed(0); A <- matrix(sample(1:3, 25, replace = T), 5)
#> A
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    3    1    1    3    3
#[2,]    1    3    1    2    3
#[3,]    2    3    1    3    1
#[4,]    2    2    3    3    2
#[5,]    3    2    2    2    1
B <- pmin(A, 2)
#> B
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    2    1    1    2    2
#[2,]    1    2    1    2    2
#[3,]    2    2    1    2    1
#[4,]    2    2    2    2    2
#[5,]    2    2    2    2    1
```

---

## update

Since you have background in computational science, I would like to provide more information.

`pmin` is fast, but is far from high performance. Its prefix "parallel" only suggests `element-wise`. The meaning of "vectorization" in R is not the same as "SIMD vectorization" in HPC. R is an interpreted language, so **"vectorization" in R means opting for C level loop rather than R level loop.** Therefore, `pmin` is just coded with a trivial C loop.

**Real high performance computing should benefit from SIMD vectorization.** I believe you know SSE/AVX intrinsics. So if you write a simple C code, using `_mm_min_pd` from `SSE2`, you will get ~2 times speedup from `pmin`; if you see `_mm256_min_pd` from AVX, you will get ~4 times speedup from `pmin`.

**Unfortunately, R itself can not do any SIMD.** I have an answer to a post at [Does R leverage SIMD when doing vectorized calculations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37214261/4891738) regarding this issue. For your question, even if you link your R to a HPC BLAS, `pmin` will not benefit from SIMD, simply because `pmin` does not involve any BLAS operations. So a better bet is to write compiled code yourself.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with R being column-major. `pmin` returns the element-wise minimum between the items passed, so the 1 is just being coerced into an object of the same dimensions. For example, if different size vectors are passed, you get a warning about elements being recycled.

Comment: Although it was not what the OP requested, there are a number of ways to realize massively parallel computations in R. Examples include the packages `snow`, `multicore`, `foreach`, `Rmpi`, `Rth`, `gputools`, and the base package `parallel`, which has merged a few of these formerly separate packages. Here's a [good reference](https://books.google.com/books/about/Parallel_Computing_for_Data_Science.html?id=SsbECQAAQBAJ) about the state of the art on this topic.

Comment: "For example, OP's problem can not benefit from this form, becomes it is memory bound. Setting up multiple threads will cause slow down." Why? Wouldn't it be a standard task in parallel programming to split the matrix into separate chunks and let each one be treated by a separate thread? There is no need to communicate between the threads in this case. This looks to me like a standard example of an embarrassingly parallel situation, which can be treated easily with R.

Comment: No problem. We can leave it at that if you like. I don't want to start a dispute, I just don't see your point in this case. This looks to me like a quite different situation compared to the Cholesky decomposition that you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

The question is slightly confusing because `min()` *is* vectorized. In order to obtain the desired result in this specific case, it is however not necessary to use this function. *Logical subsetting* provides a probably more efficient (and certainly more compact) alternative.

If I understood your desired output correctly, a modification of the matrix as performed by the nested loops in your code can be achieved with a single command:

```
temp_mat[temp_mat > 1] <- 1
```

Hope this helps.

---

```
set.seed(123)
temp_mat <- matrix(2*runif(50),10)
#> temp_mat
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] 0.5751550 1.91366669 1.7790786 1.92604847 0.2856000
# [2,] 1.5766103 0.90666831 1.3856068 1.80459809 0.8290927
# [3,] 0.8179538 1.35514127 1.2810136 1.38141056 0.8274487
# [4,] 1.7660348 1.14526680 1.9885396 1.59093484 0.7376909
# [5,] 1.8809346 0.20584937 1.3114116 0.04922737 0.3048895
# [6,] 0.0911130 1.79964994 1.4170609 0.95559194 0.2776121
# [7,] 1.0562110 0.49217547 1.0881320 1.51691908 0.4660682
# [8,] 1.7848381 0.08411907 1.1882840 0.43281587 0.9319249
# [9,] 1.1028700 0.65584144 0.5783195 0.63636202 0.5319453
#[10,] 0.9132295 1.90900730 0.2942273 0.46325157 1.7156554
temp_mat[temp_mat > 1] <- 1
#> temp_mat
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] 0.5751550 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 0.2856000
# [2,] 1.0000000 0.90666831 1.0000000 1.00000000 0.8290927
# [3,] 0.8179538 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 0.8274487
# [4,] 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.00000000 0.7376909
# [5,] 1.0000000 0.20584937 1.0000000 0.04922737 0.3048895
# [6,] 0.0911130 1.00000000 1.0000000 0.95559194 0.2776121
# [7,] 1.0000000 0.49217547 1.0000000 1.00000000 0.4660682
# [8,] 1.0000000 0.08411907 1.0000000 0.43281587 0.9319249
# [9,] 1.0000000 0.65584144 0.5783195 0.63636202 0.5319453
#[10,] 0.9132295 1.00000000 0.2942273 0.46325157 1.0000000
```