# k-permutations of an integer n in R

Tags: r, permutation

The function

```
permutations(n)
```

from package `e1071`, returns a matrix containing all permutations of the integers 1:n (one permutation per row). For example:

```
> permutations(3)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    1    3
[3,]    2    3    1
[4,]    1    3    2
[5,]    3    1    2
[6,]    3    2    1
```

A weaker meaning of the term permutation indicates those ordered arrangements in which no element occurs more than once, but without the requirement of using all the elements from a given set. I'm considering, in particular, the arrangements of a fixed length k of elements taken from a given set of size n, in other words: k-permutations of n.

How can I obtain a matrix containing all k-permutations of the integers 1:n (one permutation per row)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `permutations` from `gtools` is more elaborate than the one from `e1071` as it has other arguments as well like r, v etc.

For your case you can use

```
library(gtools)
gtools::permutations(n,k)
```

Edit: this function `permutations` is from `gtools` package as pointed out by @jaySf

Adding an example of `gtools::permutations(3,2)`

```
permutations(3,2)

         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    1    2
    [2,]    1    3
    [3,]    2    1
    [4,]    2    3
    [5,]    3    1
    [6,]    3    2
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the `arrangements` package. After [some benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233816/1100107), we concluded that it is very good.

```
> library(arrangements)
> permutations(3,2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    1
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    3    1
[6,]    3    2
```

Comment: This is very fast, indeed.