# R creating combinations with replacement

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a small example like the following:

```
df1 = data.frame(Id1=c(1,2,3))
```

I want to obtain the list of all combinations with replacement which would look like this:

[image]

So far I have seen the following functions which produces some parts of the above table:

a) combn function

```
t(combn(df1$Id1,2)) 

# Does not creates rows 1,4 and 5 in the above image
```

b) expand.grid function

```
expand.grid(df1$Id1,df1$Id1) 

# Duplicates rows 2,3 and 5. In my case the combination 1,2 and 2,1 
#are the same. Hence I do not need both of them at the same time.
```

c) CJ function (from data.table)

```
#install.packages("data.table")
CJ(df1$Id1,df1$Id1)

#Same problem as the previous function
```

For your reference, I know that the in python I could do the same using the itertools package (link here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/itertools-combinations-with-replacement/problem)

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: I think you're asking for 'unique combinations' rather than 'with replacement', which to me is about sampling and means something different. Using that search term you'll see there are some related questions already, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563565/r-find-all-possible-unique-combinations

Comment: @arvi1000 You are correct. My bad for confusing the two. Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative using `expand.grid` by creating a unique `key` for every combination and then removing duplicates

```
library(dplyr)

expand.grid(df1$Id1,df1$Id1) %>%
   mutate(key = paste(pmin(Var1, Var2), pmax(Var1, Var2), sep = "-")) %>%
   filter(!duplicated(key)) %>%
   select(-key) %>%
   mutate(row = row_number())


#  Var1 Var2 row
#1    1    1   1
#2    2    1   2
#3    3    1   3
#4    2    2   4
#5    3    2   5
#6    3    3   6
```