# R - Number of cases in 4-dimensional pairwise array

Tags: r, pairwise

I'm making a "pairwise" array in R. Given the vector `combo`, I'm finding every permutation of 4 elements. Thus, a **4-dimensional "pairwise" array.** My current approach is making it as a simple `list`, using nested `sapply` functions, like so:

```
fourList <- sapply(X = combo, FUN = function(h) {
    hi <- which(combo == h) #get index of h

    sapply(X = combo[hi:n], FUN = function(i) {
      ii <- which(combo == i) #get index of i

      sapply(X = combo[ii:n], FUN = function(j) {
        ji <- which(combo == j) #get index of j

        sapply(X = combo[ji:n], FUN = function(k) {
          list(c(h,i,j,k))
        })
      })
    })
  })
```

I'd like to make some sort of progress indicator, so I can report to the user what percentage of the array has been built. Ideally, I'd just take `numberCasesCompleted` and divide that by `totalCases = length(combo)^4` to get the fraction that is done. **However, I can't seem to figure out an algorithm that takes in `hi`, `ji`, and `ii`, and outputs the value `numberCasesCompleted`. How can I calculate this?**

In the 2D (`x` by `y`) case (e.g: `sapply(X, function(x) {sapply(X[xi:n], function(y) {list(c(x,y))}}`), this could be calculated by `sum(n - (x-2:x), y-(x-1))`, but generalizing that to 4 dimensions sounds rather difficult.

Comment: Any particular reason you're rolling your own permutation algorithm rather than using a optimized version?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use `for` loops instead of `sapply`, and create a `numberCasesCompleted` counter that increments each time through the inner loop.

Comment: @Gregor I'm not aware of an optimized version. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have tried using `for` loops (and indeed, incrementing a simple counter worked great for that), but `apply` functions are **so** much faster. I'm working with a dataset where `length(combo) = 127`, so it takes a **long time** (several hours) to run with `for` loops, while `apply` gets the job done in a few minutes.

Comment: [This answer is extremely thorough for all combinatorial needs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47983855/903061). I'd be willing to bet it's recommendation, `rcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(combo, 4)` is at least 3 orders of magnitude faster than the `sapply`/`list` approach on a decently-sized input.

Comment: Also `sapply` and `apply` aren't that different from `for`. If you see that much of a difference between `for` and `sapply` then you are doing something wrong in the `for` loop code. [See here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2275896/903061). I'd suggest getting a code review of your `for` loop code to figure out what you're doing to slow it down so badly.

Comment: In fact, newer versions of R (>= 3.4.0) with JIT compilation can have `for` faster than `sapply`. Try out `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
 sapply = sapply(1:n, I),
 for_loop = {result = integer(n); for(i in 1:n) result[i] = I(i)},
 times = 10
)` to see. When I just ran it, `for` came out about 0.02 seconds faster than `sapply`.

Comment: And yes, `RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(v = 1:127, m = 4)` takes less than 3 seconds on my laptop. No progress bar needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid. Just add the proportion complete of the first level to the proportion complete of the second level (scaled down to a single iteration at the first level), and so forth.

In my case: `completion <- hi/(n+1) + (ii/(n+1))*(1/n) + (ji/n)*(1/n)*(1/n)`

(The `n+1` denominators are there because there's effectively another loop after `hi` is equal to `n`, as `ii` still has a full set of iterations to complete. Otherwise it would end at ~101%. But for a rough/quick estimation of progress, this is fine.)

However, it is worth noting that (according to @Gregor in the comments) there are [much better ways of making combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569176/r-permutations-and-combinations-with-without-replacement-and-for-distinct-non-d/47983855#47983855) in R, so my original use case may be moot (just don't use nested `sapply` in the first place).