# Specific sequence creation in R

Tags: r, combinations

I want to create the following sequences in a smart way instead of hard-coding them:

```
'0-0-0-0-0-0'
'0-1-0-0-0-0'
'0-0-1-0-0-0'
'0-0-0-1-0-0'
'0-0-0-0-1-0'
'0-0-0-0-0-1'
'1-0-0-0-0-0'
'1-1-0-0-0-0'
'1-0-1-0-0-0'
'1-0-0-1-0-0'
'1-0-0-0-1-0'
'1-0-0-0-0-1'
'1-1-1-1-1-1'
'2-0-0-0-0-0'
'2-1-0-0-0-0'
'2-0-1-0-0-0'
'2-0-0-1-0-0'
'2-0-0-0-1-0'
'2-0-0-0-0-1'
'3-0-0-0-0-0'
'3-1-0-0-0-0'
'3-0-1-0-0-0'
'3-0-0-1-0-0'
'3-0-0-0-1-0'
'3-0-0-0-0-1'
'0-2-0-0-0-0'
'0-0-2-0-0-0'
'0-0-0-2-0-0'
'0-0-0-0-2-0'
'0-0-0-0-0-2'
 and so on...
```

Elaborating more on the details of the pattern that presents: I have 4 states `{0,1,2,3}` and I want to find all the possible combinations for sequences of `length=6` starting with any of the states and allowing only one intermediate position of the sequence to be present in any of the next positions.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what "and so on..." means. For example, is `3-0-2-0-0` one of things covered? How many elements are you trying to generate all together?

Comment: is this expand.grid ?

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, it is one of those elements I want to create. I do not know how many will be created in total, but only one of the positions after the first one can be in another state than 0 given all different states at position one.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that should yield `4*(3*5+1) = 64` possibilities.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *intermediate position*? Do you just mean "at most one other non-zero", or are  there restrictions (like perhaps the one other non-zero must be less than the first value).

Comment: Intermediate positions = positions after the first one. In these positions, I want each status to appear only once, in each position, given all possible statuses at the first position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one method. I generate a simple description of each sequence, then build the sequences (and de-duplicate, which is needed because of the all-intermediate-0 items).

```
dd = expand.grid(first = 0:3, inter_value = 0:3, inter_position = 2:6)

result = t(apply(dd, 1, function(x) {
  z = c(x["first"], rep(0L, 5))
  z[x["inter_position"]] = x["inter_value"]
  z
}))

result = result[!duplicated(result), ]

dim(result)
# [1] 64  6
head(result, 10)
#       first          
#  [1,]     0 0 0 0 0 0
#  [2,]     1 0 0 0 0 0
#  [3,]     2 0 0 0 0 0
#  [4,]     3 0 0 0 0 0
#  [5,]     0 1 0 0 0 0
#  [6,]     1 1 0 0 0 0
#  [7,]     2 1 0 0 0 0
#  [8,]     3 1 0 0 0 0
#  [9,]     0 2 0 0 0 0
# [10,]     1 2 0 0 0 0
```

Getting the dashes:

```
apply(result, 1, paste, collapse = "-")
#  [1] "0-0-0-0-0-0" "1-0-0-0-0-0" "2-0-0-0-0-0" "3-0-0-0-0-0" "0-1-0-0-0-0" "1-1-0-0-0-0" "2-1-0-0-0-0"
#  [8] "3-1-0-0-0-0" "0-2-0-0-0-0" "1-2-0-0-0-0" "2-2-0-0-0-0" "3-2-0-0-0-0" "0-3-0-0-0-0" "1-3-0-0-0-0"
# [15] "2-3-0-0-0-0" "3-3-0-0-0-0" "0-0-1-0-0-0" "1-0-1-0-0-0" "2-0-1-0-0-0" "3-0-1-0-0-0" "0-0-2-0-0-0"
# [22] "1-0-2-0-0-0" "2-0-2-0-0-0" "3-0-2-0-0-0" "0-0-3-0-0-0" "1-0-3-0-0-0" "2-0-3-0-0-0" "3-0-3-0-0-0"
# [29] "0-0-0-1-0-0" "1-0-0-1-0-0" "2-0-0-1-0-0" "3-0-0-1-0-0" "0-0-0-2-0-0" "1-0-0-2-0-0" "2-0-0-2-0-0"
# [36] "3-0-0-2-0-0" "0-0-0-3-0-0" "1-0-0-3-0-0" "2-0-0-3-0-0" "3-0-0-3-0-0" "0-0-0-0-1-0" "1-0-0-0-1-0"
# [43] "2-0-0-0-1-0" "3-0-0-0-1-0" "0-0-0-0-2-0" "1-0-0-0-2-0" "2-0-0-0-2-0" "3-0-0-0-2-0" "0-0-0-0-3-0"
# [50] "1-0-0-0-3-0" "2-0-0-0-3-0" "3-0-0-0-3-0" "0-0-0-0-0-1" "1-0-0-0-0-1" "2-0-0-0-0-1" "3-0-0-0-0-1"
# [57] "0-0-0-0-0-2" "1-0-0-0-0-2" "2-0-0-0-0-2" "3-0-0-0-0-2" "0-0-0-0-0-3" "1-0-0-0-0-3" "2-0-0-0-0-3"
# [64] "3-0-0-0-0-3"
```

Comment: How can I get the output in the format  of "0-0-0-0-0-0"  (string with dashes) instead of the current one?

Comment: Added the dashes at the bottom.

Comment: I was expecting more statuses. E.g. statuses 0-1-1-0-0-0, 0-1-1-1-0-0 etc. are missing. I'd like if possible to include all possible combinations

Comment: I don't understand. You stated "only one intermediate position of the sequence to be present", and defined "intermediate position" as *all positions after the first*. Maybe the issue is the definition of "present", but my answer, the other answer, and the comments all assumed "present" to mean *not zero*. You also said "I want each status to appear only once, in each position" To me, 0-1-1-0-0-0 has 2 intermediate positions present and the 1 appears twice, therefore it is doubly invalid. If that's not what you want, I would recommend asking a new question with a clearer explanation.

Comment: Generally, over a week after multiple answers were posted is late to be fundamentally changing the questions requirements, I think you'll have more success getting the answer you want by considering this question complete and asking a new question, perhaps using this one as a reference, than by editing this one so late.

Comment: You're absolutely right; my mistake. I just want to see the difference between the two snippets in order to better understand the code, so as to generate any future sequences without asking a question.

Comment: We'd take a much simpler approach to generate all combinations, something like `all_combi = do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(0:3), 6))` in base R (which is just a fancy way to write `expand.grid(0:3, 0:3, 0:3, 0:3, 0:3, 0:3)`). Or using non-base packages, `RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(0:3, 6, repetition = TRUE)` would work.

Comment: For general combinations and permutations, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47983855/903061) is extremely thorough.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general nested for-loop solution. Not the most efficient in the world, but gets the desired result (Note: You can change `states` and/or `sequence_len` and the sequences will be generated automatically):

```
states <- 0:3
states_len <- length(states)
sequence_len <- 6
sequence_mat <- matrix(0, states_len*{{states_len-1}*{sequence_len-1}+1}, sequence_len)
rw <- 1
for(ii in states){
  for(jj in states){
    for(kk in 2:sequence_len){
      if(jj != 0){
        rw = rw + 1
      }
      sequence_mat[rw, 1] <- ii
      sequence_mat[rw, kk] <- jj
      if(jj == rev(states)[1] && kk == sequence_len){
        rw = rw + 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
> head(sequence_mat, 20)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1
 [7,]    0    2    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    2    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    2    0
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    2
[12,]    0    3    0    0    0    0
[13,]    0    0    3    0    0    0
[14,]    0    0    0    3    0    0
[15,]    0    0    0    0    3    0
[16,]    0    0    0    0    0    3
[17,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
[18,]    1    1    0    0    0    0
[19,]    1    0    1    0    0    0
[20,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
```