# R all permutations per vector entry

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
x <- c("a b c", "d e")
```

with splitted entries

```
str_split(x, " ")
```

I want to get all permutations per splitted vector entry, so the result should be

```
c("a b c", "b c a", "c a b", "a c b", "b a c", "c b a", "d e", "e d")
```

I tried to use function

```
permutations(n, r, v=1:n, set=TRUE, repeats.allowed=FALSE)
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/22569176/680068

Comment: Another related/possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/q/11095992/4137985

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating all distinct permutations of a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095992/generating-all-distinct-permutations-of-a-list-in-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the `str_split` step , you can use `combinat::permn` to create all possible permutation of the string and paste them together.

```
result <- unlist(sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(x) 
                 combinat::permn(x, paste0, collapse = " ")))
result
#[1] "a b c" "a c b" "c a b" "c b a" "b c a" "b a c" "d e"   "e d"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `pracma::perms` like below

```
unlist(
  Map(
    function(v) do.call(paste, as.data.frame(pracma::perms(v))),
    strsplit(x, " ")
  )
)
```

which gives

```
[1] "c b a" "c a b" "b c a" "b a c" "a b c" "a c b" "e d"   "d e"
```