# How to get a set of all Combination in R with given conditions?

Tags: r

I have a set:

```
lynx <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,7,8,9)
```

I want to return a set of all combinations with repetitions allowed from the above set, for example:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 8 9
```

I used the combination function from library gtools but it doesn't help

I tried:

```
combination(n = 9, r = 5, v =  lynx, repeats.allowed=TRUE)
```

which returned

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
    [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
    [2,]    1    1    1    1    2
    [3,]    1    1    1    1    3
    [4,]    1    1    1    1    4
```

But the issue is that it also returns,

```
  [152,]    1    1    2    8    8
```

which I don't want since there are no two 8s in the set.

Comment: I suspect you want `permutations(n = length(lynx), r = 5, v =  lynx, set = FALSE)`.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work

Comment: @Roland won't that produce multiple copies of some indistinguishable vectors? For example, there would be 154,440 rows consisting solely of 1s. It looks like the OP wants such identical rows collapsed to a single instance. It would also output 69 million rows if it completed

Comment: @azmath the result of this calculation is so vast, it does raise the question of why you would need to precalculate all such instances. Why not sample as required? If you just want to calculate the number of permutations there are mathematical shortcuts.

Comment: @AllanCameron Calculation took about two minutes on my system. Removing duplicates is easy.

Comment: @Roland my cloud based server gave up after about two minutes, though to be fair it only has 8 GB of RAM. I'm sure you managed it on a decent computer (I'm guessing the resultant vector should be about 1.4 GB) - but difficult to see the purpose without more info from the OP.

Comment: @AllanCameron According to RStudio, the result is a matrix of 2.8 GB. R's RAM usage went up to 6.3 GB (it isn't freed by the garbage collector immediately). I have 32 GB of RAM.

Comment: @AllanCameron What Roland gave is not what Im looking for. It should not be that large a set

Comment: @azmath no, but you can remove duplicates easily enough from it. Are you sure you need the whole set? Can I ask what your use case is?

Comment: @azmath It seems that you are looking for a way to generate combinations/permutations without replacement but with non-distinct items (a.k.a [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)). Please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22569328/10802499), which did a fairly straightforward walk-through of 8 basic combinatoric problems, including the one you have encountered.

Comment: One way is to create a matching vector `lyncidx <-  1:length(lynx)`  , do standard combination or permutation on that set, and then use the results to index into `lynx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ekoam

```
lynx <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,7,8,9)

comb <- combinations(freq = table(lynx), k = 5, x = unique(lynx))

comb
```

library: arrangements

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a matching vector `lyncidx <-  1:length(lynx)` , do standard combination or permutation on that set, and then use the results to index into `lynx` .
`lyncidx` contains all distinguishable items, so standard set theory tools work fine.  Then, e.g.,  for an output of  `foo = 1,7,12,20`  you would grab the values of `lynx[foo]` to get

`1,1,1,2`  as desired

Comment: Hu Carl, what do you mean by indexing lynncidx to lynx?

Comment: @azmath  Use the values in `lyncidx` to create your collection of combinations.  Then for each combination created,  use that vector to select the elements of `lynx` for your final "actual" combinations of `lynx` elements.