# R combn fails when asked for large number of combinations (even though memory should suffice)

Tags: r, combinations

I wanted to get all the combinations for 73,000 choose 2 and I tried to use `combn` in order to calculate it.

```
combn(73000,2)
```

I received the following error:

```
Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) :
invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
```

I figured that the number of combinations is *2,664,463,500* so multiplied by 8 should yield around *22GB* which I had free on my machine.
So even though it's a lot of combinations, it shouldn't fail.
Any alternative way to calculate the number of combinations or explanations of why combn fails?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47983855/4408538 near the bottom.

Comment: Thank you! I missed that when I was looking for a solution. Do you know any alternatives to cbind as well? After I was successfully able to get 2 vectors I was willing to use them as coordinates for indexing a matrix. At the end instead of coordinates indexing I resorted to use linear indexing.. But I would love to know if there is a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the code and apparently when constructing the output matrix the dimensions are converted to integer:

```
count <- as.integer(round(choose(n, m)))
out <- matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) # matrix for now
```

Eliminating the `as.integer` from `count` increases its range and in my case it doesn't overflow anymore.
It wasn't enough though, I continue to receive the same error again.
I couldn't find a way to initialize the matrix as type integer, so I created two vectors instead (m=2)like that:

```
col1 <- vector(mode="integer", length=n)
col2 <- vector(mode="integer", length=n)
```

With few more adjustments it runs now.

I hope this might help to others as well.